# Is it possible to stream ffmpeg output to a virtual webcam/virtual capture device/AVFoundation object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ffmpeg, video-streaming, avfoundation, webcam

I would like to stream live video from a remote computer onto a texture in Unity3D.  Currently, I am able to get the stream into my local machine via a combination of netcat and ffmpeg.  I would like to be able to have ffmpeg output the stream to a virtual webcam to take advantage of Unity3D's easy to use webcam texture.  The local machine is running OSX.

Do you have any virtual video capture device recommendations for OSX?

Answer (score 2):

On GNU/Linux you could use `v4l2loopback`, can't say on OSX.